# How to find how many times each letter appears in a name?

Tags: python, python-3.x

My code:

```
name=input("Enter name:")
print("Frequency of letters:",dict((letter,name.count(letter)) for letter in set(name)))
```

But this prints the output in dict format.
But I want my output like this:

```
Frequency of letters: b-2,o-1
```

How to make my code to print in this format. Please do help and show the  change in code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: firstly use counter from collections module then iterate it using for loops and print it.

Comment: Is there a way around without using counter?@AlbinPaul

Comment: just plain dictionary is one way, why wouldn't you want functionality thats already implemented?

Comment: No I just want a simple code which checks the given username and counts the letters in it without using import,dict etc., How to do that? @AlbinPaul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a dict at all. This takes care of only the lowercase letters in the alphabet, without using any import (although using [`string.ascii_lowercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_lowercase) would have been more useful).

```py
name = 'bob'
print("Frequency of letters:",','.join(('{}-{}'.format(letter,name.lower().count(letter))
        for letter in set(name.lower())
        if letter in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")))
```

Comment: Yes but `dict` will be more efficient. `name.count` will be O(n) for each letter

Comment: Is there a way just to give name as string and directly get the letter count in string,involving no dict convertion at all? @usr2564301

Comment: But this doesn't work for names with spaces for example ria ria. How to modify this for getting output in string for an input which is also a string.(without using import,dict or any other data structures? @usr2564301

Comment: ? It counts *everything* in your input. Including spaces. I don't see the problem.

Comment: But I want to exclude space count. Can you please tell me how to do that?@usr2564301

Comment: And is it possible to count the occurrence of each letter without using import and also without converting to dict like you showed in your answer? @usr2564301

Answer (score 1):

If your dict code is right:

```py
name=input("Enter name:")
count_dict = dict((letter,name.count(letter)) for letter in set(name))
format_string_list = [f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in count_dict.items()]
# or generator
# format_string_gen = (f"{k}-{v}" for k, v in count_dict.items())
print(f"Frequency of letters:{','.join(format_string)}")
```

Comment: Is there a way just to give name as string and directly get the letter count in string,involving no dict convertion at all? @DustyPosa

Answer (score 1):

Try this below :

```
name = input("Enter name:")
output_dict = {}
for i in name:
    if i in output_dict:
        output_dict[i] += 1
    else:
        output_dict[i] = 1
for i in output_dict:
    print("Frequency of Letters: ", i, "-", output_dict[i])
```

Comment: Is there a way just to give name as string and directly get the letter count in string,involving no dict convertion at all? @Abhishek Kulkarni

Answer (score 0):

Use Counter to count frequency. Also I do not think you need space to count if there is one. So omit the space and then format the string

```
from collections import Counter
import re

name = 'John Jonson'    
name= re.sub('\s','',name)

for k,v in Counter(name).items():
    print('{}-{}'.format(k,v), end=",")
```

Without using Counter

```
d={}
for letter in name:
    d[letter] = d.get(letter, 0) + 1

for k,v in d.items():
    print('{}-{}'.format(k,v), end=",")
```

Comment: Is there a way just to give name as string and directly get the letter count in string,involving no dict convertion at all? @mad_

Comment: Why you do not want to convert it to a dict which would be much faster than otherwise

Comment: No I just want a simple code which checks the given username and counts the letters in it without using import,dict etc., How to do that? @mad_

Comment: use `count` then but it would be in-efficient and many have already posted as an answer. But *wihtout using import.dict* is not sufficient enough to say that you are performing a task by overlooking the complexities underneath.

Comment: How exactly should I do that with count? Can you elaborate please? @mad_

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the desired output

```
from collections import Counter 

test_str = input()

count = Counter(test_str)

for k, v in count.items():
    print(k + '-' + str(v) + ',', end=' ')
```

Comment: Is there a way just to give name as string and directly get the letter count in string,involving no dict convertion at all? @Dhaval Taunk